# Django - Anonymous user group

Tags: django

I need to allow administrators to manage permissions for models on my site. Groups, Users, and Permissions are doing a great job of this right now. However, I also need to allow the administrators to manage the permissions of non-authenticated users - Anonymous Users. The docs say that anonymous user's group is always empty, so how can I allow administration of their permissions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is strange to add permissions to anonymous users. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#authorization-for-anonymous-users) say:

> Django's permission framework does not have a place to store
> permissions for anonymous users. However, it has a foundation that
> allows custom authentication backends to specify authorization for
> anonymous users. This is especially useful for the authors of
> re-usable apps, who can delegate all questions of authorization to the
> auth backend, rather than needing settings, for example, to control
> anonymous access.

So you can set permissions to anon yuser, but with custom auth backend.
It is sometimes better to use declarative permission check, using decorators on the views with the needed permissions, like:

```
@permission_required('somemodel.can_add')
def add_model(request):
```

or leave it unrestricted for everyone(incl. anonymous user). Or some custom permission check..

Or if you want to have permissions anyway, you can always create a dummy user, let's say "AnonUser", to give it permissions, and then checking permissions to have something like:

```
if not user.is_authenticated():
    dummy_user = User.objects.get(name="AnonUser")
    if dummy_user.has_perm("somepermission"):
        # bla bla bla
```

but this is something I'd never use..

Comment: The dummy user approach may be my only option, given that I need to let administrators manage anon perms from the admin. It does feel icky, though...

Comment: Then it is probably better to implement a simple auth backend, and to force anon users to be logged with the dummy user. And to disable the anonymous user at all.

Comment: Perphaps you can assign the dummy user in a middleware class?

Answer (score 1):

I've gone with a custom backend to provide an anonymous group (as [@Tisho suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11317148/1888983)), which can easily be edited from the admin interface. Add the following class to `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` in `settings.py` (e.g. `'appname.auth_backend.AnonymousPermissions'`).

Note that it's common to require a login before checking permissions (e.g. with `login_required`), which will have to be replaced with permission only checks.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class AnonymousPermissions(object):

    def get_anonymous_permissions(self):
        #largely from django.contrib.auth.backends
        group, group_created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Anonymous')
        perms = group.permissions.all()
        perms = perms.values_list('content_type__app_label', 'codename').order_by()
        perms = set("%s.%s" % (ct, name) for ct, name in perms)
        return perms

    def get_group_permissions(self, user_obj, obj=None):
        if user_obj.is_anonymous:
            perm_cache_name = '_anonymous_perm_cache'
            if not hasattr(user_obj, perm_cache_name):
                setattr(user_obj, perm_cache_name, self.get_anonymous_permissions())
            return getattr(user_obj, perm_cache_name)
        return set()

    def get_all_permissions(self, user_obj, obj=None):
        return self.get_group_permissions(user_obj, obj)

    def has_perm(self, user_obj, perm, obj=None):
        return perm in self.get_group_permissions(user_obj, obj)
```